# How to make a calendar view in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

is it possible to create a page that looks like a calendar ( Pretty much like the basic calendar app on your phone) with xamarin.forms ?

I've been searching and all i see is some prenium widget from companies.

I'm new to xamarin.forms and im unsure if this will be possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  XF has a grid layout, and a calendar is basically a grid of cells.

Comment: Sorry but what is XF ? So i'd have to create a grid layout for each month of the year basically ?

Comment: "Xamarin Forms".    I would create a single grid and just use databinding to populate the data

Comment: 30s of searching: https://github.com/lilcodelab/Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar, or https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Comment: Ok nice, idk if i'll be able to use that tho (It's for an app at my job), seems like its gonna be a though one to recreate this haha

Comment: You don't have to remake wheels , the third-party plugin is pretty easy to use .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamForms.Controls;assembly=XamForms.Controls.Calendar"
```

```html
    <StackLayout>  
        <controls:Calendar Padding="10,0,10,0"   
                           SelectedBorderWidth="4"   
                           DisabledBorderColor="Black"  
                           ShowNumberOfWeek="false"  
                           StartDay="Monday"  
                           TitleLabelTextColor="Purple"  
                           TitleLeftArrowTextColor="Blue"  
                           SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"  
                           SpecialDates="{Binding Attendances}"  
                           DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}"/>  
    </StackLayout>
```